# Return Hash from PHP

Tags: php, excel

Is there any way to return the hash from PHP to an Excel spreadsheet?. The call to this method would be done from a cell of an Excel spreadsheet

```
<?php

    $user = $_POST["user"];
    $pwd = $_POST["pass"];

    function PleaseNow($user, $pwd)
    {
        $salt = "\$5\$rounds=5000\$" . "something" . $user . "\$";
        return crypt($pwd, $salt);

    }
    echo PleaseNow($user, $pwd);

?>
```

Comment: Encrypting != Hashing. Encrypting can be reversed, hashing is a one-way function which is what you'd want for a password. If you need to produce a hash you want to use `hash()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php

Comment: It's also worth noting, hashing alone is not enough for passwords, I see you've got a salt which is good, but something like Bcrypt is an even better option, and easier to implement/update in the future!.. Is your question how to call a PHP function from Excel, or how to insert data from PHP into a spread sheet (or file)

Comment: P.s. either way, you'd have to use Macros (VBA) to make the call to a web service (PHP backed) then handle the data returned in VBA to populate the cell/s